# text contains another field (power query)

Tags: filter, powerquery

i need to filter a field which contains another field in the same query.

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], [SANTIYE]))
```

the error i got is

> Expression.Error: The field 'SANTIYE' of the record wasn't found.

full code :

```
let

    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Query1,{"Sicil No", "TARIH"},#"IK Bordro",{"Personel Kodu", "Bordro Tarihi"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "NewColumn", {"Santiye", "Taseron", "Turk/Yerel"}, {"Santiye", "Taseron", "Turk/Yerel"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded NewColumn",{{"TARIH", type date}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Bordro", each if [#"Turk/Yerel"] = "YEREL" then "YEREL BORDRO" else if Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], "RUBLE") then "TURK RUBLE" else if Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], "USD") then "TURK USD" else if Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], "RUB") then "TURK RUBLE" else if Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], "IZIN") then "TURK IZIN HAKKI" else if Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], "IHBAR") then "TURK IHBAR HAKKI" else if Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], "KIDEM") then "TURK KIDEM HAKKI" else "DIGER" ),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Conditional Column",{"Sicil No", "HESAP ADI", "TARIH", "ACIKLAMA", "Santiye", "Taseron", "Turk/Yerel", "Bordro", "Ruble Tahakkuk", "USD Tahakkuk"}),


    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [Santiye] <> null),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], [Santiye] ))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

any ideas, workarounds ?

Comment: after adding a new line as source and correcting the syntax , i got a new error **Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.**

Comment: i cannot put he whole code here (character limits) but the new part of the code is

`filtreleme = #"Muhasebe Bordrolari" [SANTIYE] ,
    
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Reordered Columns", each [Santiye] <> null),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA], filtreleme ))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are mixing up step names and field names?

It works fine with me [as you can see here](https://youtu.be/rYwy6drSsfs).

Code generated:

```
let
    Source = ..... (table created, code not relevant),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ACIKLAMA", type text}, {"SANTIYE", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each Text.Contains([ACIKLAMA],[SANTIYE]))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. field names are correct. i feel it looks like a circular reference error in excel

Comment: the point is i hate case-sensitive systems )))  I had to write `SANTIYE` as `Santiye`